# 2 errors when calling AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, audiotoolbox, vibration

I'm making an app which vibrates once a timer reaches a certain limit.

However, when calling

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Xcode comes up with two errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[drawGraph drawRect:] in drawGraph.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

and

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas on what is causing these errors?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image]

If you simply must not add the header files only, as shown above, a framework must be added to your project. and you should a following header. `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

> 1. In Xcode, click your project file at the top of the Project Navigator.
> 2. Click 'YourProjectName' under "Targets"
> 3. Click the "Build Phases" tab.
> 4. Click the plus in the "Link Binary With Libraries" window.
> 5. Add the AudioToolbox.Framework library
> 6. Add `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

[image]

Comment: Turns out I hadn't added the framework to my project. Thank you so much!